# Simulating exponential Vasicek/Ornstein-Uhlenbeck

Tags: stochastic-processes, simulations, mean-reversion, vasicek, ornstein-uhlenbeck

I am trying to simulate commodity prices using the exponential Vasicek/Ornstein-Uhlenbeck model from [Schwartz 1997](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1540-6261.1997.tb02721.x) p. 926 Equation (1). I am using the closed form solution from [Vega 2018](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s13662-018-1718-4) p. 5 Equation (9) which is:

$$\ln(X_{t})=\ln(X_{t-1})e^{-\theta \Delta t}+\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta}\right)(1-e^{-\theta \Delta t})+\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\theta}(1-e^{-2\theta \Delta t})}\epsilon_i$$

Here is my code in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(123)


def gen_paths(X0, theta, mu, sigma, T, num_steps, num_sims):
    dt = float(T) / num_steps
    paths = np.zeros((num_steps + 1, num_sims), np.float64)
    paths[0] = X0
    for t in range(1, num_steps + 1):
        rand = np.random.standard_normal(num_sims)
        paths[t] = np.exp(np.log(paths[t-1]) * np.exp(-theta * dt) 
           + (mu - (sigma ** 2) / (2 * theta)) * (1 - np.exp(-theta * dt)) 
           + np.sqrt((1 - np.exp(-2 * theta * dt)) * (sigma ** 2) / (2 * theta)) * rand)
    return paths


X0 = 5
theta = 0.4
mu = 5
sigma = 0.15
T = 1
num_steps = 365
num_sims = 5

paths = gen_paths(X0, theta, mu, sigma, T, num_steps, num_sims)
plt.plot(paths[:, :10])
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('time steps')
plt.ylabel('index level')
plt.show()
```

And here is the result I am getting:
[image: Simulation exponential Vasicek/Ornstein-Uhlenbeck]

This is certainly not the result I expected, I expected the path to fluctuate around the long term mean $\mu$ and not a exponential rise.

**Question: Did I misunderstood the exponential Vasicek/Ornstein-Uhlenbeck meaning that this result is correct and expected or is there something wrong in my simulation?**

Update:

Here is my new function after the suggestion in the answer below:

```
def gen_paths(X0, theta, mu, sigma, T, num_steps, num_sims):
    dt = float(T) / num_steps
    paths = np.zeros((num_steps + 1, num_sims), np.float64)
    paths[0] = X0
    for t in range(1, num_steps + 1):
        rand = np.random.standard_normal(num_sims)
        z = np.log(paths[t-1])
        paths[t] = z * np.exp(-theta * dt) 
           + (mu - (sigma ** 2) / (2 * theta)) * (1 - np.exp(-theta * dt)) 
           + np.sqrt((1 - np.exp(-2 * theta * dt)) * (sigma ** 2) / (2 * theta)) * rand
    
    paths_new = np.exp(paths)
    return paths_new
```

Comment: Why do they make OU exponential instead of using traditional OU?

Comment: @develarist Because that is what [Schwartz 1997](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1540-6261.1997.tb02721.x) uses and is used a lot in other literature as well.

Comment: my question is why do they use it

Comment: and why do you expect the path of exponential OU to fluctuate around the long term mean $\mu$ and not an exponential rise, when it is traditional OU that is the one that does fluctuate around $\mu$

Comment: @devalarist Because it doesn't in e.g. [A Stochastic Processes Toolkit for Risk Management](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.4210.pdf) p.32 Figure 18. Also modelling commodities would seem very wrong if this indeed was the expected result in my opinion.

Comment: @develarist Why they use it I'm not entirely sure, probably because they thought it does make a good fit to commodities.

Comment: what i'm trying to say is that you're expecting the exponential OU to fluctuate around $\mu$ just like how traditional OU fluctuates around $\mu$, which doesn't make sense to me why you would expect both to behave the same. One is an exponential of the other, what do you expect

Comment: @develarist I get that, but it does seem like the exponential does also fluctuate roughly around $\mu$, not the same as the normal OU though. Maybe I formulated it poorly, I never expected the same results as the normal O/U, I was just trying to say that based on my research the result I am getting can't be correct and my expectation was for the results to still fluctuate somewhere around $\mu$.

Comment: Welcome Quant SE, @Tharmis!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to adjust your Python a bit to:

```
...

def gen_paths(X0, theta, mu, sigma, T, num_steps, num_sims):
    ...
    for t in range(1, num_steps + 1):
        rand = np.random.standard_normal(num_sims)
        paths[t] = paths[t-1] * np.exp(-theta * dt) 
           + (mu - (sigma ** 2) / (2 * theta)) * (1 - np.exp(-theta * dt)) 
           + np.sqrt((1 - np.exp(-2 * theta * dt)) * (sigma ** 2) / (2 * theta)) * rand
    return paths
```

Specifically, you need to get rid of the `exp / log` stuff. You can take the exponential of the paths after simulation - or you incorporate the `exp / log` properly (not shown in my code above).

Comment: The results from your code look a lot more likely, but am I still simulating the same stochastic process? Care to explain what exactly is wrong with the `exp / log` stuff or how I can fix that? I used exactly the formula from the mentioned paper, so I am not sure why in Python it should be different.

Comment: I think you had one closing bracket at the wrong place. If you look carefully, you can replace $ln(X_t)$ with some variable $z_t$ everywhere in your code and simply do the $exp$ing afterwards. HTH

Comment: I did exactly that (see the Update in my question) however that also doesn't work. If I don't immediatly do the `exp`ing the values in the `log` get negative which yields to an error. Did I misunderstand you somehow?

Comment: I think that you can literally just copy my code and calculate exp of the resulting vector afterwards.

Comment: That gives me values around 140, but since my $X_0$ and $\mu$ is 5 that is not the correct result. Either I am completely missing something or my results are correct and I just misunderstood the exponential O/U completely.